# Bash For Loop: Convert URL to .jpg File and Retain URL id in Image Filename

Tags: bash, loops, imagemagick

I am new to bash. I've written the following for loop to convert an array of URLs to image files using basename:

```
for i in ${img_jpg[@]//\"/} ; do convert "$i" -set filename:base "%[basename]" "%[filename:base].png" ; done
```

It's working well for URLs that are formatted like this:

https://xxx.domain.com/xy22233

Now I would like to create a similar loop to that uses basename without the file extension for urls like this:

https://img.domain.com/vi/y2x112233/default.jpg

I would like to output a file with just this part of the URL:

y2x112233

Or even the entire URL.

This is my attempt but it hasn't worked:

```
for i in ${img_jpg[@]//\"/} ; do convert "$i" "${filename%.*}" ; done
```

Comment: `basename $(dirname "https://img.domain.com/vi/y2x112233/default.jpg")`?

Comment: That does look like it would work. Do you happen to know how to incorporate that into the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do the loop with ImageMagick convert.

```
filelist="https://img.youtube.com/vi/--1uHerc2Ns/hqdefault.jpg"
for file in $filelist; do
dir=$(dirname $file)
base=$(basename $dir)
echo $dir
echo $base
echo $file
convert $file $base.jpg
done
```

Change your "for" loop at desired.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. While this does extract the string I want, it does it before the convert statement so it only echos the ID and it doesn't product a .jpg file.

Comment: The files I listed are bogus. You have to provide your own proper URLs. Once you have valid URLs, then it should work. Try one simple command with a valid URL of the form `convert https://img.domain.com/vi/y2x112233/default.jpg result.jpg` If that does not work, then you may need to edit your ImageMagick  policy.xml file to give permission to use HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the basic convert statement does work. I'm using the code you have above defining filelist as my array: filelist=${img_jpg2[@]//\"/} My error is: convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229. But it does also echo the correct ID. I've validated the array and used it in the other loop, so I don't thing the array is a problem.

Comment: What do you get from `filelist=${img_jpg2[@]//\"/}; echo $filelist`  Does that print the correct names? Do any of the files have spaces in the names? Please show the results here. In what directory are you issuing that command? Does it contain your files?

Comment: I have edited the command in my answer and it seems to work with that URL. So try your filelist command in that code. You can remove the echo commands if it works.

Comment: It works! I can't thank you enough for your time and effort. I will upvote when my reputation is better :) Again, thank you so much. You made my day!!!